# How to return Task output from an anonymous method?

Tags: c#

I've this method:

```
public async Task Method1Async()
{
    var foo = 1;
    var bar = 100;

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       // add below code here
    }       
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

and I want to add this code to the `tasks` above and wait for all to finish:

```
// do something
await Method2Async(foo, bar); 
// do something else
```

How can I do that? Thanks..

---

I tried this, but `Task.WhenAll` waits for ever:

```
public async Task Method1Async()
{
    var foo = 1;
    var bar = 100;

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(new Task(async () =>
        {
            // do something
            await Method2Async(foo, bar); 
            // do something else
        }
    }       
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: You're not starting the new tasks in `tasks`.

Comment: You [probably shouldn't be using the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) either.

Comment: @juharr sorry I didn't understand you

Comment: @Blendester When you pass an action to the `Task` constructor it does not immediately run the action.  You have to call `Start`.  Or instead you can use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead.  Though honestly my suggestion would be another `async` method as I think that would be more readable.

Comment: @juharr oh yes thanks a lot.. I replaced `new Task` with `Task.Run` and it works well. you could add this as the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the `Task` directly:

```
tasks.Add(Method2Async(foo, bar));
```

If you want to do some work around it you can construct an async lambda and invoke it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Func<Task> f = async () => {
        //do something
        await Method2Async(foo, bar);
        //do something else
    }
    tasks.Add(f());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But something needs to be done before and after it.. maybe I need a third method? I preferred if I could do it with anonymous method somehow

Comment: Or use chaining `ContinueWith()`